# StackTrace, line info of fluent call

Tags: c#, stack-trace

Given the following fluent API calls:

```
Foo()
    .Bar1(() => { ... })
    .Bar2(() => { ... })
    .Bar3();
```

I want to determine code file and line number of the Bar1, Bar2 and Bar3 lines later down (eh... up) their call stack...

**Case 1:** ...inside the Bar1/Bar2/Bar3 extension methods.

*My current solution:* I immediately create a stack trace inside those methods and find the information.

*Open problems:* Line information belongs to the `Foo()` line, not the `Bar#(...)`-line :(

**Case 2:** ...later on, somewhere completely else in the code, in case the given delegate throws an exception when executed.

*My current solution:* I examine the stack trace of the exception and find the correct line : )

**Special case 3:** Bar3 defines the delegate inside the method, I still want to now the `.Bar3()` line when such a delegate throws an exception.

*My current solution:* Don't know yet, the delegate is created somewhere else and I can't use the same method as in case 2. My only chance is the information from Case1, however, that information is not completely correct (wrong line number).

**Q:** Do you know how to determine the correct code file and line number in all three cases?

*Note:* Performance is not so relevant as this is part of a testing framework.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, this entire line relates to one line of code.. I'd hazard a guess that visual studios debugger also sees this as such. I think you would have to split this into 3 separate method calls

Comment: You can set a breakpoint on the delegates, even though you have to select it first and then set the breakpoint. Little bit tricky but it works.

Answer (score 2):

.NET 4.5 includes [Caller Information Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540.aspx) which are a much cleaner way of doing just this:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

...

public Foo Bar1(
    Action, 
    [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
    [CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
    [CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)
{
    ...
}
```

The great benefit here is that you don't have to do anything at run-time. The parameters are provided at compile time, so this has no effect on the performance of your methods. Unfortunately, there's nothing preventing user code from bypassing this, for example:

```
Foo().Bar1(() => { ... }, "not a real method", "not a real file", -123);
```

Comment: I also +1'd your answer, however, although my users are not going to overwrite those method arguments (shooting their own foot...) it really makes my API "dirty". So any other answers are welcome as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is effectively a single line, so the info is not *wrong* per-se. You're gonna need to split it:

```
var foo = Foo();
var bar1 = foo.Bar1(() => { ... });
var bar2 = bar1.Bar2(() => { ... });
var bar3 = bar2.Bar3();
```

This is the easiest and fastest "fix" I can think of. You may leverage `region`s too for additional clarity:

```
#if(DEBUG)
// When compiling in debug
var foo = Foo();
var bar1 = foo.Bar1(() => { ... });
var bar2 = bar1.Bar2(() => { ... });
var bar3 = bar2.Bar3();
// additional code might be needed, depending on the real code...
#else
// When compiling in Release
Foo()
    .Bar1(() => { ... })
    .Bar2(() => { ... })
    .Bar3();
#endif
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, this is even worse for my API users ;-)